# Realm cloud - global realm

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am really excited about Realm Cloud and started building an app in my beta account.

I have my realm URL's like this:

```
static let MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS = "myInstance.us1.cloud.realm.io" // <- update this

static let AUTH_URL  = URL(string: "https://\(MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS)")!
static let REALM_URL = URL(string: "realms://\(MY_INSTANCE_ADDRESS)/users")!
```

Then I log a user in like this:

```
let credentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: self.userName.field.text ?? "", password: self.password.field.text ?? "", register: true)

SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: RealmConstants.AUTH_URL) { (_, error) in

}
```

I log in and I see the user created successfully. However, I can not interact with the global realm. I understand this is by design in the latest ROS I would like to see a clear code example how to allow a new user access to the global realm.